# Как запретить кэширование таблицу стиле при помощи javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я хочу запретить для одного файлов стилей кэш.

Что у меня получилось сделать самому, но в этом варианте происходит не приятый момент, периодически на 1 сек сайт остается без стилей вообще, так как этот код запускается по функции.

```
var date = new Date().getTime();
    document.head.innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css?='+date+'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date().getTime();
document.head.innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css?='+date+'">';
```

Comment: Это уже ответ или пример кода который вы используете ?

Comment: Это вариант в котором есть минус описанный выше, но он работает.

Comment: Тогда на этапе формирования html, т.е на бекенде, подключайте так же но через тег, тогда задержки не будет (ну если стили не весят по 500кб

Comment: Проблема в том что на страницу загружается код через ajax, нет возможности сразу загрузить на этапе формирования html

Comment: Тогда пересмотрите архитектуру, стили грузите сразу а html через ajax.в ином случае загрузка стилей будет зависеть от скорости интернета. А это чревато уже другими проблемами

Comment: Вот я и думаю может есть возможность подгрузить их после формирования html

Comment: Если после то всегда будет задержка.

Comment: Как вариант - рендерите страницу уже после загрузки стилей. Визуально будет лучше но по производительности просядешь

Answer (score 0):

Решил свою проблемой создания контейнера виде div, который будет обновляться и не будет вспышке без стилей.

```
<div id="styles" style="display:none;"></div>

    var date = new Date().getTime();
    document.getElementById('styles').innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css?='+date+'">';
```